# Is there a more elegant/efficient way of executing this macro?

Tags: vba

I have developed this macro using VBA that will populate a number of charts on a dashboard that is pulling from a dataset on another sheet. The way i have set it up is there are several tables that populate based on the desired reporting period. The tables are set to filter the entries that = 0 so that the charts are only displaying the relevant information.

I am a novice at programming and currently althought the macro works it soemtimes gets hung up and is overall pretty clunky and inefficient. Is there an easy way to make this thing run a bit smoother/faster?

Thanks,

Mike

```
   Private Sub Calendar1_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = CDbl(Calendar1.Value)
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Calendar1.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Calendar2_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = CDbl(Calendar2.Value)
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Calendar2.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Sheets("Supervisor NC").Range("supervisor_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2

Sheets("Customer NC").Range("customer_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2

Sheets("Captain NC").Range("captain_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2

Sheets("Commodity NC").Range("commodity_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2

Sheets("Customer Specific Supervisor").Range("customer_spec_super").AutoFilter Field:=2

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("a2"), Target) Is Nothing Then



        Calendar1.Left = Target.Left + Target.Width - Calendar1.Width
        Calendar1.Top = Target.Top + Target.Height
        Calendar1.Visible = True
        ' select Today's date in the Calendar
        Calendar1.Value = Date
    ElseIf Calendar1.Visible Then Calendar1.Visible = False
    End If

   If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("b2"), Target) Is Nothing Then



        Calendar2.Left = Target.Left + Target.Width - Calendar2.Width
        Calendar2.Top = Target.Top + Target.Height
        Calendar2.Visible = True
        ' select Today's date in the Calendar
        Calendar2.Value = Date
    ElseIf Calendar2.Visible Then Calendar2.Visible = False
    End If

Sheets("Supervisor NC").Range("supervisor_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

Sheets("Customer NC").Range("customer_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

Sheets("Captain NC").Range("captain_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

Sheets("Commodity NC").Range("commodity_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

Sheets("Customer Specific Supervisor").Range("customer_spec_super").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Private Sub Calendar1_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = CDbl(Calendar1.Value)
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Calendar1.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Calendar2_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = CDbl(Calendar2.Value)
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Calendar2.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    'if Target.Column = 1 and Target.Row = 1 then    you can also specify rows and cols here

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Sheets("Supervisor NC").Range("supervisor_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2

    Sheets("Customer NC").Range("customer_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2

    Sheets("Captain NC").Range("captain_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2

    Sheets("Commodity NC").Range("commodity_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2

    Sheets("Customer Specific Supervisor").Range("customer_spec_super").AutoFilter Field:=2



    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("a2"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        Calendar1.Left = Target.Left + Target.Width - Calendar1.Width
        Calendar1.Top = Target.Top + Target.Height
        Calendar1.Visible = True
        ' select Today's date in the Calendar
        Calendar1.Value = Date
    ElseIf Calendar1.Visible Then
        Calendar1.Visible = False
    End If


    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("b2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Calendar2.Left = Target.Left + Target.Width - Calendar2.Width
        Calendar2.Top = Target.Top + Target.Height
        Calendar2.Visible = True
        ' select Today's date in the Calendar
        Calendar2.Value = Date
    ElseIf Calendar2.Visible Then
        Calendar2.Visible = False
    End If

    Sheets("Supervisor NC").Range("supervisor_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

    Sheets("Customer NC").Range("customer_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

    Sheets("Captain NC").Range("captain_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

    Sheets("Commodity NC").Range("commodity_nc").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

    Sheets("Customer Specific Supervisor").Range("customer_spec_super").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will test this out tomorrow when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Works Great! Thank you for the help. I do notice one more issue though. Sometimes all of the charts don't update right away. Right now I have the macro in the worksheet selection change and to update all the charts sometimes you have to change selection multiple times. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

Comment: I am honestly humbled by your kind words.